# ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, cuda, tensorflow

```
    [xx_xx@xxxx ~]$ python multiply.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiply.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/luohao/.usr/bin/python2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/luohao/.usr/bin/python2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "/home/luohao/.usr/bin/python2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/client_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "/home/luohao/.usr/bin/python2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "/home/luohao/.usr/bin/python2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/luohao/.usr/bin/python2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I execute python command, a "ImportError" error occurs.Some solved it by adding "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64" in the /etc/profile.I try it but do no effect.I find the "libcudart.so.7.0" in /usr/share/man/man7/libcudart.so.7 by executing the whereis command and have no idea what should I do next to solve it.

Comment: You should give the path to the 7.0 cuda installation and not 5.5. Default would be `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64`.

Comment: Is that  to say the version of cuda must not less than 7.0? @havogt

Comment: Your program, apparently, is looking for the cuda runtime library version 7.0. This library comes with the cuda toolkit 7.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is being raised because the loader cannot find version 7.0 of the CUDA runtime on your system. [TensorFlow requires CUDA 7.0.](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#install_cuda)

From the path in your question (`/usr/local/cuda-5.5/...`) it looks like you have CUDA 5.5 installed. The solution is to upgrade your CUDA runtime to version 7.0, which is available from NVIDIA [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-70).